# Exporting entire table structure, but data ONLY from certain tables via phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have access to phpMyAdmin, but NOT the MySQL command line.

I need to recreate the table structure elsewhere along with certain tables that need to be 'pre-populated'. I can, of course, export the empty table structure and then export the tables one-by-one, but is there a better way to export a bunch of table data together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click on the database name at the top left and then click the Export tab you can select which tables you want to export at the left. You will still do 2 exports, first for all the structures, and then a second one for the data with only the tables that you need.

Comment: oh crap... that was exactly what i needed! shucks - and it was RIGHT in front of me!